# How do I call detail view using mvc 4 web api project

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I'm working on mvc 4 web api project

```
<a class="hover-wrap fancybox" href="Groups/Detail">
Details</a>
```

So for above I tried like

```
<a class="hover-wrap fancybox" onclick="getDetails('${Id}')">
    Details</a>

function getDetails(id) {
        $.getJSON(
                "api/groupvalues/Details" + id,
                function (data) {
               //some code
}
```

> In controller is it same like normal `ActionResult` or `Get` in web api project?

Please clear

```
    public ActionResult Detail(Guid Id)
            {
//some code               
 return View("Group",model);
            }
```

OR

```
public string Get(int id)
        {
            return "value";
        }
```

> want to render on Details page with data

Comment: do you want it to redirect to a details page or populate a partial view on the page?

Comment: @MattBodily want to redirect to `detail.cshtml` as I'm showing all detail info on that page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you just want a link that will redirect you can build the link like this

```
@Html.ActionLink("Detail", "ControllerName", new { id = Model.Id })
```

where it passes the id that was passed to the view to the details method.

Edit:

if you want to show the details of the item that was clicked you have to use jquery

```
$('.clickedItem').on('click', function(){
    window.location = '@Url.Action("Detail", "ControllerName", new { id = "----" })'.replace("----", $(this).id());
});
```

Comment: Agree but then what should be my `function getDetails(id) {
        $.getJSON(` it is same as I shown in questions above?
please guid
Then what is the use of JSON call :(

Comment: json calls in my experience are for manipulating the page you are on.  getting a partial view, validating the form, etc.  If you are just redirecting you shouldn't need the json call.

Comment: ok great but I'm not having any Model . 
instead I want to send a current clicked ID as input?

Comment: I did like this 
href="@Url.Action("Detail", "Group", new { id = "AF0EAED2-C338-4880-9BF5-40473462E5B3" })

now only problem is how to take ID value when I click on any particular item?

Comment: replace the url on the href in your link tag to "#",  the jquery will take care of that for you.  Put the id of the record that you want to send to the details page as the id of the link tag.  If your click event is on that a tag my script should work to attach the id and redirect where you want to go

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45824/discussion-between-ashuthinks-and-matt-bodily)

Comment: but i want to use a json pure web api not a actionresult :(